# Mejor forma de usar un stream java 8 con clase y subclase

Tags: java-8, lambda

Estimada comunidad, tengo un problema en la forma como usar streams, tengo 3 clases:

```
public Class A {
    String string1A;
    String string2A;
    List<B> listB;
    .
    .
    .
 }
 public Class B {
    String string1B;
    String string2B;
    .
    .
    .
 }
 public Class C {
    String string1A;
    String string2A;
    String string1B;
    String string2B;
    .
    .
    .
 }
```

Luego tengo un método que devuelve una List de C con todos los datos proveniente de una base de datos, y necesito crear un List A que tenga agrupados todos los datos, como el valor de agrupación es el String1A, lo que se me ocurrió fue esto:

```
List<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();

    Set<String> listString1A = listC.stream().map(x->x.getString1A()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());

for(String stringFilter1A: listString1A){
    A a = listC.stream()
               .filter(x->getString1A().equals(stringFilter1A))
               .map(x-> new A(x.getString1A(),x.getString2A))
               .findFirst().get();
    List<B> listB = listC.stream()
                         .filter(x->getString1A().equals(stringFilter1A))
                         .map(x-> new B(...))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    a.setListB(listaB);
    listaA.add(a);
}
```

¿Existe una manera de hacer dicha consulta usando únicamente streams o intentando eliminar el for?

Comment: No lo entiendo, en el `for` defines una variable `string1A` pero no parece que lo uses en el *stream*... ¿quizás hayas cambiado `x` por `string1A`?

Comment: @SJuan76 lo siento, ya recombré la variable.

Comment: La verdad es que el nombre de los atributos no ayuda a seguir el código

Comment: ¿Qué pasa con string2A? También está en A y C... ¿no agrupas por él?

Comment: Sí, la idea era crear un hash y un equals respecto al atributo String1A de la clase A, y luego es más sencillo usar un groupingBy

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré una solución.
Se debe crear en la clase A la implementación del hash y el equals con la variable string1A, de manera consistente. Luego realizar el filtro más o menos así:

```
Map<A, List<B>> map = listC.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        c -> new A(...),     // construct new A instance out from c instance
        Collectors.mapping(
            c -> new B(...), // construct new B instance out from c instance
            Collectors.toList())));
```

y luego un foreach para guardar dentro de las llaves A los valores List, similar a esto:

```
map.forEach((a, listB) -> a.setListB(listB));
```

Luego, se toma el Set de todas las llaves, y ya tengo un Set que cada elemento tiene como atributo valores de List.

Lo tomé de esta respuesta que hice en inglés:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823123/best-way-to-use-stream-with-class-and-subclass